# Flutter send a document with multiple copies of multiple names to a printer in desktop/web app

Tags: flutter, printing

I'm creating a form editing with Flutter for desktop/web app. The problem is the documents needs to be printed with multiple names. If I have a list of 100 names, then I need to print the form 100 times, each with a different name.

One way I see is generating a PDF file of 100 pages, replacing the name (use https://pub.dev/packages/pdf, https://pub.dev/packages/printing or https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf), then send the PDF file to the printer.

But I wonder is there a way that I can send the document and the list of names directly to the printer (in a kind of printer's format), that I don't have to generate the intermediate PDF file.

If you know a way, please comment. Thank you for you help!